# Problem deploying scheduled EJB to Glassfish server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I have a weird (?) problem with an EJB I want to deploy to my Glassfish 3.1 application server.

I have this bean, which should be executed continuously in Glassfish using the `@Schedule` annotation. This worked fine for me until I added some code to the EJB accessing a database.

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean implements MyBeanLocal {

    @Schedule(second = "*", minute = "*", hour = "*")
    public void initiateProcess() {

        MyCoordinator mc = new MyCoordinatorImpl();
        List<Entity> entities = mc.methodAccessingDB();
    }
}
```

This is my EJB, which is executed every second. How I said above, I **can** deploy this EJB and it executed successfully, if I **don't** call `ac.methodAccessingDB()`. 
This means, that I can't even deploy it to Glassfish. Glassfish tells me

> Invalid ejb jar [...]: it contains zero ejb. Note: 1. A valid ejb jar
>   requires at least one session, entity (1.x/2.x style), or
>   message-driven bean. 2. EJB3+ entity beans (@Entity) are POJOs and
>   please package them as library jar. 3. If the jar file contains valid
>   EJBs which are annotated with EJB component level annotations
>   (@Stateless, @Stateful, @MessageDriven, @Singleton), please check
>   server.log to see whether the annotations were processed properly..
>   Please see server.log for more details.

If I just write `List<Entity> entities = null;` instead of `List<Entity> entities = ac.methodAccessingDB();` I can deploy it and it runs fine.

Comment: There's an error in the code above. The variable name is `mc` but you are invoking `methodAccessingDB` on `ac`.

Comment: Ah. ok. my mistake I changed the names before posting to Stackoverflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now I have found the solution for this problem. The EJB couldn't find the classes on the deployed version. The solution was to pack everything into an **ear** project. I am using maven, so I created in the end 3 projects.

- one for the EJB `<packaging>ejb</packaging>`
- one for the EAR `<packaging>ear</packaging>`
- and a third parent project, which integrates the both other projects as `<module>`.

I then deployed the packed ear to Glassfish and the timer started and everything was there.